# What is a 2-stage estimator?

Tags: estimation, econometrics, 2sls

I thought I would quickly find the answer to this, and maybe my capabilities of using the sites search function are very poor, but I didn't find an answer to the definition of what a 2-stage estimator is. Maybe it's a case where the answer is so obvious that it doesn't need a definition.

Is it an estimator that computes the estimate by first making an intermediate computation (the first stage), the result of which is then used in the second (and final) stage ?

Comment: Can you give some context? A citation/link/reference where this occurs?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have read about this in econometrics where they regress an endogenous IV on instrumental variables to obtain predicted values, which 
 are then used in place of the original (endogenous) variable in an OLS regression. I think they call this 2-stage least squares.